# htaccess redirect old site to 2 different domains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

ok so heres the scenario:

i got a blog on the root directory of my host then i hosted some app on a subfolder named fsGallery. now, i bought a new domain for my blog and another domain for my app. ii would like to know the proper htaccess 301 redirects in order for me to redirect the old directories to their respective new domains

here's a sample dir structure:

```
root/
  /app
  [blog]
```

trying to:
redir /app to newdomainforapp.com
redir [blog] to newdomainforblog.com

also, originally, my app used to accept url parameters like this:
app/user/1234567

so i would also like to:
redir /app/user/{dynamic int parameter} to newdomainforapp.com/profile/{dynamic int parameter}

can anyone help me plox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule)s should work fine.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?app/user/([0-9]+) http://newdomainforapp.com/profile/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?app(/(.*))?$ http://newdomainforapp.com/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://newdomainforblog.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You'll probably need to play around with the groups to redirect articles properly.

Comment: I actually like David's suggestion better--did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly not programming-related, but anyway: the proper way to do this is in the virtual host configuration file (i.e. in the `<VirtualHost *:80>` ... `</VirtualHost>` section), not in an `.htaccess` file.  The directives to use are

```
 RedirectMatch permanent /app/user/([0-9+]) http://newdomainforapp.com/profile/$1
 Redirect permanent /app http://newdomainforapp.com
 Redirect permanent / http://newdomainforblog.com
```

Comment: i was only being hosted by my friend in a subdomain previously so i don't have any access to server specific files. but anyways thanks for this also. it might come in handy now that i have my own host.

Comment: Redirect and RedirectMatch work in .htaccess.  Check their documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_alias.html

Comment: @outis: True, but still, the proper way to use them is to put them in the main server configuration file. In fact, putting directives in the vhost config file is nearly always preferably to using .htaccess files.